# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Было все нормально, но после переустановки Android Studio появились проблемы, не знаю как исправить. Помогите пожалуйста )

```
package com.example.turismgeofence;

public class MyGeofence {
private static final int time = 60000;

private int id;
private int transitionType;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private double radius;

public MyGeofence(int id, double lat, double lng, double radius, int type)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = lng;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.transitionType = type;
}

public Geofence toGeofence()
{
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(String.valueOf(id))
            .setTransitionTypes(transitionType)
            .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, radius)
            .setExpirationDuration(time)
            .build();
}
}
```

Вот такие ошибки появляются

```
D:\Android\TurismGeofence\app\src\main\java\com\example\ turismgeofence\MyGeofence.java
Error:(26, 12) error: cannot find symbol class Geofence
Error:(28, 28) error: package Geofence does not exist
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Что за класс `Geofence`, он в том же пакете?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Если я правильно понимаю, то это класс для работы с Геозонами гугл

Comment: точно, вот он https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence Тогда где импорт этого класса в исходном коде?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja В том и проблема, что оно почему то не дает импортировать. Вот я добавляю строку import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence; но пишет Can't resolve symbol 'Geofence'

Comment: Зависимости проверьте в проекте, как тут написано https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup В вашем случае должно присутствовать `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4`

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, спасибо большое, проблема в зависимостях была